# Can Cypher do phonetic text search with only a part of the text, without using elastic search?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, text-search, elasticsearch-phonetic

Say I have a job as financial administrator (j:Job {name: 'financial administrator'}).

Many people use different titles for a 'financial administrator'. Therefore, I want abovementioned job as a hit, even if people type only 'financial' or 'administrator' **and** their input has typos (like: 'fynancial').

CONTAINS only gives results when the match is 100% - so without typos.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: we are not yet there, but we will get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while, this is how I solved my question.

```
MATCH (a)-[:IS]->(hs)
UNWIND a.naam AS namelist
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(namelist) YIELD value
WITH value AS search_str, SPLIT('INPUT FROM DATABASE', ' ') AS input, a
CALL apoc.text.phonetic(input) YIELD value
WITH value AS match_str, search_str, a
WHERE search_str CONTAINS match_str OR search_str = match_str
RETURN DISTINCT a.naam, label(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try fuzzy matching with a full text index and see if it solves the issue.
An example would be:
Set up the index-
`CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('jobs', ['Job'], ['name'], {})`

Query the index with fuzzy matching (note the `~`)

`CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('jobs', 'fynancial~')`

If you want to go further and use Lucene's phonetic searches, then you could write a little Java code to register a custom analyzer.

Include the `lucene-analyzers-phonetic` dependency like so:

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-phonetic</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Then create a custom analyzer:

```
@ServiceProvider
public class PhoneticAnalyzer extends AnalyzerProvider {


    public PhoneticAnalyzer() {
        super("phonetic");
    }

    @Override
    public Analyzer createAnalyzer() {
        return new Analyzer() {
            @Override
            protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String s) {
                Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer();
                TokenStream stream = new DoubleMetaphoneFilter(tokenizer, 6, true);
                return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, stream);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I used the DoubleMetaphoneFilter but you can experiment with others.
Package it as a jar, and put it into Neo4j's plugin directory along with the [Lucene phonetic jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-phonetic/8.5.1) and restart the server.
Then, create a full text index using this analyzer:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.createNodeIndex('jobs', ['Job'], ['name'], {analyzer:'phonetic'})`

Querying the index looks the same:

`CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes('jobs', 'fynancial')`